# Understanding recursion tree for withdrawal formula

Tags: algorithms, trees, recursion, efficiency

$$
T(n) = T(n-a) + T(a) + cn
$$

Now the solution says that the height of the tree $(h)$ is: 
$$
h = \left \lfloor n/a \right \rfloor
$$

And I don't understand why. Maybe I didn't understand the withdrawal formula as needed.

Comment: What would the withdrawl/withdrawal formula be? If you don't tell us, we cannot possibly know what you mean by it. Try to put yourself in our shoes.

Comment: The recurrence holds for values of $n$ that are $a$ units apart. By setting $S(m):=T(am)=T(n)$ we rewrite as

$$S(m)=S(m-1)+S(1)+cam.$$

The solution is a quadratic polynomial in $m$.

Answer (score 0):

Your recurrence expands into a recurrence tree in the following way. Each node has a label. If the label $n$ is $a$ or smaller, then the node is a leaf. Otherwise, the node has two children, one labeled $n-a$, the other one labeled $a$.

Suppose that you create this tree starting with a root labeled $n$. The root has two children: one is labeled $n-a$, and the other one, labeled $a$, is a leaf. The node labeled $n-a$ has two children, one labeled $n-2a$, and the other one is a leaf. And so on.

It takes roughly $n/a$ steps until this process terminates (since we start with $n$, have to get to $a$ or less, and drop by $a$ each time). Therefore the height of the tree is roughly $n/a$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align}T(n)&=T(n-a)+T(a)+cn
\\&=T(n-2a)+T(a)+c(n-a)+T(a)+cn
\\&=T(n-3a)+T(a)+c(n-2a)+T(a)+c(n-a)+T(a)+cn
\\&\cdots
\end{align}$$

The recursion stops after $k$ substitutions, in such a way that $n-ka$ is no more a function of $n$. In other words, when

$$0\le n-ka<a.$$

---

The solution of the recurrence is

$$T(n)=T(n-ka)+kT(a)+cnk-c((k-1)+(k-2)+\cdots0).$$

The final summation is a triangular number, $\dfrac{(k-1)k}2$.

---

Technically, the solution $\left\lfloor\dfrac na\right\rfloor$ is not necessarily correct, as no base case of the recurrence is given. All we could say is that the height of the tree is the $k$ such that we know the value of $T(n-ka)$, and our assumption $0\lt n-ka<a$ is somewhat arbitrary.